# How to make my Cloud Function only be called from my GCP service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-cloud-tasks

As seen below I am editing the permissions for access to my Cloud Function called `task`. I am following the advice from GCP that says the following:

> This resource is public and can be accessed by anyone on the internet.
> To remove public access, remove "allUsers" and "allAuthenticatedUsers"
> from the resource's members.

so that my function can only be called from my GCP. So I removed the `allUsers` access for the `Cloud Functions Invoker` role. But now I am trying to add a new member (service account) with the `Cloud Functions Invoker` role:

[image]

[image]

However I don't know what service account my Cloud Tasks are fired from. I've created a new service account with only Cloud Tasks permissions but I don't know how to actually make my Cloud Tasks use this service account when executing. There doens't seem to be an option for that:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#sa

Comment: Did the previous link help?

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. Javier the link states that you can choose which service account a task is fired from so yes it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Google docs, "Cloud Tasks can call HTTP Target handlers that require authentication if you have a service account with the appropriate credentials to access the handler."

You may need to create a service account and give the appropriate roles to it.

Please follow the official Google documentation [1] where the steps to follow are detailed.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#sa

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Service Account with appropriate permissions and set it as "Runtime service account" at the time of function creation:

[image]

You can also check the Documentation here, which provides `gcloud` commands as well:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#console_2